# A list of objects as an attribute? How?

Tags: java, list, class, object

I want to created a class called: account - as an attribute it should get a set of all the transactions that belong to the account.. so I guess I need a list?

A List is an interface so it can't be instantiated so how do I create a list of all my transaction objects?

thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: create a an `ArrayList`, by `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>()`

Answer (score 0):

do this.`List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();`

Comment: worked for me :) thank you! Now I want to add a method that creates a new transaction and adds it to the list we just created. can u help me with that as well? sry im beginner^^

Comment: @Heisenberg BB ;)  public void addTransaction(){ Transaction t = new Transaction(); transactions.add(t);}